# Associating ImageField url with another object in django

Tags: python, django

I have two models,

```
class Core:

    def logo_path(instance, filename):
        pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
        filename = re.sub(pattern, '', filename)
        return 'images/core/logos/core_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.pk, filename)

    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=logo_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class CoreRoom(Room):
    core = models.ForeignKey(Core, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    logo_url = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)
```

I want to populate the logo_url in the CoreRoom object with the path to the logo in the Core object.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is needed as . you can always access it using `my_core_room.core.logo.url`, but the easiest way would be to override the `.save()` method of your `CoreRoom` model:

```
class CoreRoom(Room):
   ...
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.logo_url = self.core.logo.url
       super(CoreRoom, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

`logo_url` model field can be converted to property method as well, because, it is not necessary to save logo url information as it is already stored in DB. For example:

```
class CoreRoom(Room):
     core = models.ForeignKey(Core, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
     # remove logo url model field

     @property
     def logo_url(self):
          return self.core.logo.url
```